# Status expected:<200> but was:<404> in spring test while testing my spring boot test cases

Tags: spring-boot

I have created two test cases out that one was working fine. While testing for the "/account/accountNumber" endpoint, I got an error.

Below is my controller test cases:

```
package com. bank;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.apache.coyote.Response;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.bank.model.Account;
import com.bank.model.Customer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CapstoneBankProjectApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();

   
     
    
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }
    
    
    @Test
    public void testcreateAccount() throws Exception {
        
        Customer customer=new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerId(1);
        customer.setCustomerName("Manasa");
        Account account=new Account();
        account.setAccountNumber(456);
        account.setAccountType("savings");
        account.setBalance(2000.0);
        account.setCustomer(customer);
        
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        String JsonRequest=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(account);
        MvcResult result=mockMvc.perform(post("/account").content(JsonRequest).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                                .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
                
        String resultContext=result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Response response=objectMapper.readValue(resultContext,Response.class);
        
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus()==200);       
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testgetAccountById() throws Exception{
    
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/account/accountNumber").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        
        String resultContext = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        Response response = objectMapper.readValue(resultContext, Response.class);
        
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus() ==200);
            
        
      
  }

}
```

is there anything wrong?

console result:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /account/accountNumber
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.bank.controller.AccountController
           Method = com.bank.controller.AccountController#getAccountById(int)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2022-03-21 13:20:40.698  INFO 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-21 13:20:40.698  INFO 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2022-03-21 13:20:40.701  WARN 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90121, SQLState: 90121
2022-03-21 13:20:40.701 ERROR 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]
2022-03-21 13:20:40.704  WARN 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90121, SQLState: 90121
2022-03-21 13:20:40.705 ERROR 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]
2022-03-21 13:20:40.705  WARN 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to release JDBC Connection used for DDL execution
2022-03-21 13:20:40.706  INFO 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-03-21 13:20:40.711  INFO 8696 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

this is Junit console result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at com.bank.CapstoneBankProjectApplicationTests.testgetAccountById(CapstoneBankProjectApplicationTests.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

this is my controller:

```
package com.bank.controller;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bank.model.Account;
import com.bank.service.AccountService;
import com.bank.Exception.ResourceNotFoundException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        Account acc=accountService.accountCreate(account);
        if(acc!=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc,HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Account is not Created!!");
        }   
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/aclist")
    public ResponseEntity<?> accountList() throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        
        List<Account> accountList=accountService.allAccounts();
        if(!(accountList.isEmpty())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(accountList,HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("accounts not found");
        }
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/byType/{accountType}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> byAccountType(@PathVariable String accountType) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        List<Account> account =accountService.accountByType(accountType);
        if(account.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(accountType+""+"Type of account does not exist!!");
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(account,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAccountById(@PathVariable("accountNumber") int accountNumber) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        Account acc=accountService.findAccountById(accountNumber);
        if(acc!=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc,HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("account [accountNumber="+accountNumber+"] can't be found");
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/{from}/{to}/{amount}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> transferFunds(@PathVariable("from") int from,@PathVariable("to") int to,@PathVariable("amount") double amount) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        return accountService.transferFunds(from, to, amount);  
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteAccById(@PathVariable ("accountNumber") int accountNumber) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        String x=accountService.deleteById(accountNumber);
        if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("deleted")){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("deleted successfully",HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Account [accountNumber="+accountNumber+"] can't be found");
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/balance/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getBalanceById(@PathVariable ("accountNumber") int accountNumber) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        String balance=accountService.getBalanceById(accountNumber);
        
        if(balance.equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid accountNumber")) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Account [accountNumber="+accountNumber+"] can't be found");
            
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(balance,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteAll")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteAllAccounts(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(accountService.deleteAllAccounts(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }   

    @PutMapping("/update/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> UpdateAccount(@PathVariable ("accountNumber") int accountNumber,@RequestBody Account account) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        Account acc=accountService.updateAccount(accountNumber, account);
        if(acc!=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(acc,HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("invalid accountNumber and account");
        }
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/deposite/{amount}/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deposite(@PathVariable("amount") double amount,@PathVariable("accountNumber") int accountNumber) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        
        
            return accountService.deposite(amount,accountNumber);
    }
    @PutMapping("/withdraw/{amount}/{accountNumber}")   
    public ResponseEntity<?> withDraw(@PathVariable("amount") double amount,@PathVariable("accountNumber") int accountNumber) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        return accountService.withdraw(amount,accountNumber);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

for me `Assert.asserTrue(response.isStatus()==Boolean.True)` was not supporting so I used `Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus() ==200)`

Comment: Remove your `@Before` method.

Comment: please provide me with a solution

Comment: You don't need the `@Before` you are already injecting the MockMvc. This method actually makes your tests slower as you are doing the setup again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP 400 response indicates a bad request. Your HTTP GET endpoint expects an `int` while you're sending a `String` as the path variable.

So `accountNumber` must be a real number like `123`:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc
   .perform(get("/account/123")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andReturn();
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.coyote.Response` (although at least one Creator exists): no double/Double-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize      when use /account/balance/456 instead of /account/456  please suggest me what I do now

Comment: that's a new issue for another endpoint of yours. It's expecting a primitive `double` (decimal number). Please create a new question on Stack Overflow for this. 
PS: When handling monetary amounts with Java you're better of using `BigDecimal` (reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency))and I'd suggest putting such information in the HTTP body of the request not in the path (just my 2 cents).

Comment: How can I use that in my code.